# Naming custom fields of built-in objects without collisions

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I want to know, is there some standard way to name custom fields of built-in objects in JavaScript to avoid any collisions with standard fields?

For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.thisFieldIsNotGoingToBeUsed = 'by XHR internals but is used by the app';
```

It can be useful, for instance, to reverse lookup object parent in events without using loops with comparison of `this` object to each member.

There are `data-` attributes in HTML, but I can't find any JavaScript equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is to not modify what you don't own. Consider this approach for your example instead;

```
var myObj = {};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

myObj.xhr = xhr;
myObj.customProperty = 4;
myObj.customFunc = function () {
    // use this.xhr 
}

// Now pass myObj around instead, you have a reference to xhr (myObj.xhr)
// and your customProperty (myObj.customProperty).
```

---

Because of how closures work in JavaScript, you should also have access to the variables which were in scope when you defined your `onreadystatechange` function, which again removes the need for a `this` context completely;

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var something = function () {
    // I have access to "xhr" because of closures.
};

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        // I still have access to "something" here because of closures;
    }
}

// xhr.open && send.
```

... even if you don't have closures on your side (e.g. the `onreadystatechange` is defined in a different scope), you should be looking at modifying your code to allow you to pass the necessary variables you need in order to do your work.

Comment: But I'm making a callback, so `this` would be the `xhr` (or, in my case, `WebSocketConnection`), not `myObj`.

Comment: @SiPlus: In your callback, you should have access to the variables surrounding the request because of closures; let me update my post with an example.

Comment: Actually I meant event listeners, not callbacks. I confuse them often.